# How to get file descriptor for the port on which tcp client has been bound in twisted

Tags: python, tcp, client, twisted, file-descriptor

How can I get the file descriptor for the port on which the client has been bound.
I want this to share the port in between different processes.

I am able to get the file descriptor for the tcp server, but I am not able to get the 
file descriptor for the client. For example:

```
p=reactor.listenTCP(8005,Myfactory())
```

where `p` is the port object, here I can get the file-descriptor just by using `p.fileno()`

But in case of client

```
p=reactor.connectTCP('127.0.0','8080',MyFactory())
```

here if do `p.fileno()`

I am getting the error as follows

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

That I know it is the integer, but my question is: is there any other way to get the file descriptor for the client?

Comment: The result of `listenTCP()` is a port but the result of `connectTCP()` isn't, it is a `Deferred.` You need to have a[nother] look at the API documentation.

Comment: The result of connectTCP is a connector, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... what you want to do is a *little* bit hacky.

To start with, the result of connectTCP() is useless for you, because at this point, no connection has been made yet.

You can start thinking about extracting the file descriptor after the connection has been established, so the connectionMade() method of the protocol instance has been called. The information about file descriptor is hold by the transport, which implement ITransport interface. Unfortunately this interface does not expose information about the file descriptor, as its more general.

In case of a simple TCP connection, your transport will be the instance of twisted.internet.protocol.FileWrapper, which has a file attribute. Summing all of this, your code could look somewhat like:

```
class MyProtocol(protocol.Protocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
         print 'file descriptor is: ', self.transport.file.fileno()
```

Comment: Actually, see ISystemHandle.  It's totally opaque, so you have no idea what's going to come back from it (who even says the transport *has* a file descriptor?).  But, if you don't mind failing when there's no socket, or you know there's always a socket, then what you mean is `self.transport.getHandle().fileno()`.  And your transport is basically *never* a `FileWrapper`, ever.

Comment: @Marek Kowalski : i am getting the attribute error when ever i tried that you told me 
that is : exceptions.AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'file'

Comment: @Marek Kowalski: transport has no file attribute instead it has fileno attribute.

Thank you , you show me the way

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone: Hmm.. to be honest I haven't really tested it, I took a look into the code. Your solution is better.

Comment: Hacky is great! (unless it's something you're doing for a job)